# Move divs down when top div expands

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create an expanding menu where each header controls a div of links. In fact, everything in my code is made of divs (i.e. headers and content). Whenever I click a header div, the content div grows and reveals its contents. My problem is is that the content div pushes everything else out of the way. It squeezes itself into the middle. What I want is a fixed active header while everything below it and its contents is pushed down.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $switch = 1;
  var $last;

  // Closes drawers. Removes header 
  // selections.
  function clear() {
    $(".m-title").removeClass("active");
    $(".drawer").removeClass("open");
    $last = null;
  }

  /* • Opens/Closes drawer by its header. 
     • Enables consistent opening/closing of
       the same drawer.*/
  function load(element) {
    var $temp = element.index();

    if ($temp == $last)
      clear();
    else {
      clear();
      element.addClass("active");
      element.next().addClass("open");
      $last = element.index();
    }

  }

  // Listens for header clicks.
  $(".m-title").click(function() {
    load($(this));
  });

  // Does the same thing as clear(), but with   // a button.
  $("#button").click(function() {
    $(".m-title").removeClass("active");
    $(".drawer").removeClass("open");
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  background: #595959;
}
#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /*End FLEX*/
  min-width: 350px;
  width: 65%;
  height: 700px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  background: #191919;
  border: solid 1px #101010;
  box-shadow: -1px 1px 0px 0px #555;
}
#m-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-self: center;
  /*End FLEX*/
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 65%;
  height: auto;
  border: solid 1px red;
  color: wheat;
}
.m-title {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-self: center;
  /*End FLEX*/
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px black;
  transition: .5s;
}
.m-title:hover {
  background: rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.5);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .5s;
}
.m-title:active {
  background: rgba(75, 75, 75, 0.5);
  transition: .1s;
}
.m-title span {
  align-self: center;
  /*End FLEX*/
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 24px;
}
.m-title.active {
  background: rgba(160, 60, 60, 0.5);
  /*Highlights active header*/
}
.drawer {
  height: 0px;
  /*Closes drawer*/
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px green;
  align-self: center;
  transition: .5s;
}
.drawer.open {
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  transition: .5s;
}
#button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 75px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
}
#button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#button span {
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="m-wrap">
    <div id="m-map" class="m-title"> <span>Site Map</span>
    </div>
    <div id="m-draw1" class="drawer"></div>
    <div id="m-about" class="m-title"> <span>About</span>
    </div>
    <div id="m-draw2" class="drawer"></div>
    <div id="m-emp" class="m-title"> <span>Employee Services</span>
    </div>
    <div id="m-draw3" class="drawer"></div>
    <div id="m-serv" class="m-title"> <span>Services</span>
    </div>
    <div id="m-draw4" class="drawer"></div>
    <div id="button"> <span>clear</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/blutuu/gjxe8ndy/) of what I've created. Funnily enough, the sidebar of jsfiddle acts the way I want my menu to act. Could this be done with all divs or should I go about this in another way?

Comment: Your two "parent" or "container" divs are centered in your css. That's why they are centered and the child divs (your menu) are also centered. As to whether or not you should use all div tags, you should *try* to use the tags [as they are intended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div) but it's really up to your implementation needs.

Comment: @wahwahwah I know they're centered. That's the way I want them unless that has anything to do with why they won't stay still when I click them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it push down, change this in your css:

```
#m-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* justify-content: center;          commented out   */
  /* align-self: center;               commented out   */
```

Update on commented request

To center it within its container you can do like this:

```
#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /*End FLEX*/

  min-width: 350px;
  width: 65%;
  /* height: 700px;             commented out   */
  padding: 100px 0;         /*  added padding   */
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Any advice on how to center the whole thing again?

Comment: @blutuu Updated my answer with one way to do it.

Comment: Worked for me, thank you so very much, Asons

Answer (score 0):

Just remove or change the display property of the div id="container".
You may be abble to give a position to that div using css or jquery.